# Docker run multiple commands, tee to logfile, and missing SIGTERM

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have a problem with docker and redirect internal console output to logfile and I don't know how can I workaround it. In docker compose I run following command

```
bash -c "./redis-server redis.conf | tee -ai /redis.log"
```

Everything is fine except that redis don't receive SIGTERM at "docker-compose stop". It hangs for 10s and after this docker probably send SIGKILL. If I use simple init scripts from this urls:
[Krallin tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini)

or [Yelp dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init)

Docker stop before 10s timeout, but redis still don't receive SIGTERM and don't create dump.rdb file. Maybe somebody can help?

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout is 10 seconds, you can lower that with the `-t` argument. Have you tried without the "tee" command though? Docker works "best" with a single process running, and the `-i` tee arg (ignore SIGINT signal) may also be interfering with the shutdown process.

Comment: Command can be bash -c "./redis-server redis.conf > /redis.log" too. It still hangs, and docker kill container after timeout. I only want to see log on host console (via docker-compose) and have log in file

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what you are trying to do with the log file. Where/what is "/redis.log", a shared file? There probably is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: docker-compose show output from all containers in host console. I would like to have this output in host console, and each container log in separate file in shared volume